# Salary related question

Tags: salary

I am submitting my CV on line to a prospective employer and on the form are two questions based on salary: one is my salary at my last place of employment and the other is my expected gross salary. How do i fill in these questions? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first one seems pretty self explanatory. How much did you make per year at your previous job, before taxes?

The second, how much do you wish to ask for at your new job? Again, the number is before taxes (gross).

As for what values you fill in, we obviously can't help you with that, barring some extreme elaboration on details.